# How do you filter out data that exists in a list from a Query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm currently trying to filter an SQL query by two parameters, then order them by a date field. On top of this, each entry has a unique ID. I am trying to get the most recent row, and if that returns an undesired match to a conditional, re-query for the next item in the table. But, I have to exclude the previously found result which in only known to be unique by that ID.

This is what I have thusfar:

```
List<string> prevChecked = new List<string>;

do{

    var query = (from someRow in context.aTable
                 where someRow.Param1.Equals(param1Arg) &&
                 someRow.Param2.Equals(param2Arg)
                 // Trying to Exclude any Unique in results that have a 
                 // matching uniqueID inside of prevChecked
                 orderby someRow.RecentDate descending
                 select someRow).FirstOrDefault();

    // Use result of query, to get result of anotherQuery, 
    // if null append the query.UniqueID to prevChecked 

}while (anotherQuery != null)
```

I've tried using

```
!someRow.UniqueID.Contains(prevChecked)
```

and saw mention on one webpage of an "Except" function, though neither soultion worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add condition to your `where` clause like:

```
!prevChecked.Contains(someRow.UniqueID)
```

So your query would be:

```
 var query = (from someRow in context.aTable
                 where someRow.Param1.Equals(param1Arg) &&
                 someRow.Param2.Equals(param2Arg) &&
                !prevChecked.Contains(someRow.UniqueID)
                 orderby someRow.RecentDate descending
                 select someRow).FirstorDefault();
```

You may see: [Creating IN Queries With LINQ](http://www.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/)

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much. I was trying

   !someRow.UniqueID.Contains(prevChecked); That explains the error now.